# How to find out the current memory on the JVM?

Tags: java

I want to find out the amount of memory available in the Java Virutal Machine. I tried:

```
<< Jlink`;InstallJava[];runtime = JavaNew["java.lang.Runtime"];runtime@freeMemory[]
```

but it throws an error:

`JavaNew::argx0: "There is no constructor for class java.lang.Runtime that
takes zero arguments."`

However, the similar code:

```
dataObject = JavaNew["java.util.Date"];dataObject@toString[]
```

can print the result, although `toString` doesn't have arguments either.

What happens in Java? I noticed in the Java API that 
`freeMemory` is  **public native long freeMemory()**. 
The difference is: `toString` is **public String toString()** and `freeMemory` is native. I found native's full name is [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface),but I don't have any idea to solve this.
So how to use `freeMemory()` or `totalMemory()` etc. with JLink?

Comment: Just a warning about freememory (it's not really the total available amount), see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can achieve what you try to do:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[]
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.Runtime"]
runtime = Runtime`getRuntime[]
runtime@freeMemory[]
```

I think the reason that you can not instanciate a `java.lang.Runtime` object the usual way is that it is a singleton and the only way to get a handle to the one instance is the `` Runtime`getRuntime `` class/static method (see e.g. [oracle java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)). For that method to be available you need the call to `LoadJavaClass`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I know how to use the Runtime class now